# Added Column Not accessible in next migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have added a column to my table via a migration, but I am not able to access the added column in the subsequent migration file.

When I execute `rake db:migrate` the migration aborts, but when I execute it again the migration succeeds, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

below is the code where i am adding column

**

```
class AddIsDispatchToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :is_dispatch, :boolean, :default=>false
  end
end
```

**

Now, when i try to access the column in next migration file it fails.

The subsequent migration file has the code below

service_member = Member.create(:is_dispatch=>true)

And Here is the error that it produces

```
unknown attribute: is_dispatch/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1764:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1758:in `each'
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1758:in `assign_attributes'
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1578:in `initialize'
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:508:in `new'
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:508:in `create'
/Users//Desktop/RailsDevelopement//db/migrate/20161003121452_add_dispatch_services.rb:11:in `up'
```

Comment: Check the order of migrations. The migration that has the column, that u want to access, must be called before

Comment: the sequence is correct

Comment: When you say it initially aborts - on which migration is it aborting - is it the one that is adding the column or the one that is trying to access the column? Might be worth updating your question with that info and the code for the failing migration.

Comment: Could you also add the code for the migration that is producing the error. As a sanity check look at the database to see if the `is_dispatch` column exists as a result of running the first migration.

Comment: just updated the question with statement that produces error

Comment: Have you tried `User.reset_column_information` after 'add_column' in same migration.

Comment: Nope, the issue happens in the next migration file after adding the column.

Comment: Priyank Gupta, that worked for me. You want to submit a answer? i can accept it

Comment: @PriyankGupta - use the @ if you want someone to receive notification of a comment. Incidentally I'm still confused how that works. You are adding column to User but creating a new Member with that attribute - Is Member extended from User model?

Comment: @PriyankGupta i am creating a column in users which i am using in subsequent migrtation. it seems that the column inforamtion has to be reset if we are adding a column and refering it in subsequent migration if migrations are executed one after other

Comment: @opensource-ios Added my answer. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `User.reset_column_information` after `add_column` in same migration.